# Reason for: #1546-D: (ULP 15.1) Detected consecutive bitfield assigns. Recommend using bit mask instead

Tags: c

I am working with CCS8, using a struct and initialize the vars as shown in the Code below. CCS gives me remarks at lines 15, 16 and 17 which read as follows:

**#1546-D: (ULP 15.1) Detected consecutive bitfield assigns. Recommend using bit mask instead**

I do not really understand what benefit you would get from using bit masks in this case. I assume that this remark is a more general thing which only comes into play in strange edge cases(?) This theory is somewhat backed up by [this question on E2E](https://e2e.ti.com/support/tools/ccs/f/81/t/317480).

Code attached:

```
#include <msp430.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char var1;
    unsigned int var2;
    unsigned char var3;
    unsigned char var4;
} Test;

void main ( void )
{
    Test BOB;
    BOB.var1 = 1;
    BOB.var2 = 1;
    BOB.var3 = 3;
    BOB.var4 = 1;
}
```

I would really like to understand this remark so that i can change my coding habits accordingly if this would prevent problems which could arise in the future.

Thanks in advance for any feedback / answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I'm pretty sure it's a bug and you should consider it a false positive. See the links in the bottom.

I can't see any bitfields in the code you pasted?

It would've made sense if the code looked like this:

```
struct s
{
  char a : 4;
  char b : 4;
};

int main()
{
  struct s S;
  S.a = 0;
  S.b = 0;

  return 0;
}
```

I noticed these reports of seemingly false positives regarding that same warning, on TI's forum: https://e2e.ti.com/support/tools/ccs/f/81/t/317480?ULP-15-1-Question
https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/317382?ULP-15-1-Question

I know they're old, but unless you're using latest version of CCS, this might be a case of a false positive?

Comment: Correct i did not use bitfields. You a re probably also correct that this remark is caused by a bug in the software. Nevertheless i would like to know why this would be a problem in your example for example.

Would a assign of a value higher than the specified bitfield cause an "overflow" into the other valiable?

example:
```
  char a : 4;
  char b : 4;

s.a = 21;     //           0001 101
s.b = 8;       // 0000 1000
                   //           1001 101  <- result in memory
```
If the variables share this space in memory the result for b (saved in msb as example) would be 9 ?

Comment: Hi @Bassrelic - Your example would not cause an overflow. A compliant compiler should mask the other fields off, so that assigning to one field doesn spill over to the others. The code I wrote, was just meant to showcase bif-fields in case you weren't familiar with them - there is nothing wrong with it as such. The "problem" with bit fields is that some details regarding bitfields are implementation-defined. See https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP11-C.+Do+not+make+assumptions+regarding+the+layout+of+structures+with+bit-fields

Comment: I am pretty sure it's a bug in the TI software, but it's always a good idea to check up on such details. For instance, check out this non-exhausting list of undefined behavior in C (appendix J2): http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf#page=571 <-- there is just soooo much undefined behavior in C, it's not even funny. Don't get me wrong, I love the language, but it's easy to get hurt

Comment: Thanks @Morten Jensen for clarification + incredibly interesting links!
Verry appreciated!

You are right - that appendix is somewhat scary to read through but due to the fact i did not even know this appendix does exist, it is great to me to know a source to check behaviour i am not sure about myself.

Thanks again, this answered my question!

Comment: There is the unresolved ticket [Compiler mistakenly issues power rule 15.1 diagnostic for consecutive int, not bit field, constant assignments](https://sir.ext.ti.com/jira/browse/EXT_EP-6306), so TI recognise this as a bug.